# Deprecated methods in uml class diagramm

Tags: uml

I have to draw an uml class diagramm for an existing class. This class has deprecated methods in it and I don't know how to handle these.

I thought about strinking them out, but I don't want to "invent" something on my own and couldn't find anything online.

Is there a standard way to indicate that a method is deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First  Ask The **Question Zero:**

- Why it is important for me to draw class diagram?
- Why it is important  for me to show deprecated methods in class
  diagram?

**If you have solid reasonable answer that  satisfy** you, then the rest is simple:

In UML class diagrams for methods, the genaral pattern is like this:

> visibility name(parameter-list):return-type **{property-string}**

So you **can use property string to show that the method is deprecated** such as, assume that finished is a deprecated method which return boolean, then

> +finished() : boolean {deprecated}

And of course definitely **can use streotypes like Jim L. says.**

> +finished():boolean << deprecated >>

You can use both sterotypes and property string set extra information about a method in UML

> +finished:boolean << getter >> { query, default = false }

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  Properties are things that have semantic impact.” [OMG03b].  A good example of this would be a language directive like Java's synchronized.  using a Stereotype is as Jim L says is correct.

Comment: Stereotype is a new type of modeling element that extends the semantics of the metamodel.So both property-string and sterotype has semantic impact. To be more clear they change the meaning of model.

Comment: In the UML, a property is a named value denoting a characteristic of an element.Some properties are predefined in the UML, Others can be user-defined.

Comment: For simplicity and practical purposes, there is nothing wrong to define a property string for {deprecated} methods.

Comment: @HippiasMinor: where does the UML 2 specification allows a user-defined `{deprecated}` meta property without a stereotype that defines it?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a standard way to handle deprecation specifically, but you can use part of the UML standard to express it. We have defined our own stereotypes within our own profile. One of the stereotypes we use is «pending delete». You could define one called «deprecated», perhaps with some metadata, such as the release in which the element was deprecated. You could then apply the stereotype to any operation, class, property, etc. The stereotype will be visible for all to see.